# Unable to use umdh from Windows SDK anymore

Tags: windows, winapi, umdh

I used to use umdh for years to successfully track down memory leaks, however as of late it doesn't seem to be working anymore, even with the very latest version of the Windows SDK. The latest case of where it's not working is on Windows 11. Gflags is correctly set etc., but I always get this message:

```
Warning: UMDH didn't find any allocations that have stacks collected.
Warning: Traces could not be callected because the Stack Trace Database is full.
Warning: Increase the size of the Stack Trace Database using GFLAGS.
```

All attempts to tweak the size of the stack trace DB have not resolved the issue.

Comment: According to a Microsoft employee, this is a known problem. I quote: "Yeah. It's not working and I don't know when/if it will ever be."

Comment: I can't make it to work on Windows 10 21H2....

Comment: I also quote an email I got from a Microsoft Support guy: "Anyway, I have confirmation it is broken.  The dev team owning the exe knows about it and when they can get to fixing it they will."

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Switched to the Windows Performance Toolkit / xperf now.
https://digitalhouseblog.wordpress.com/2010/12/20/using-the-windows-performance-toolkit-to-find-memory-leaks/

Comment: Did you manage to have meaningful results with xperf on a recent Windows 11 Enterprise 64 bits OS?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem. Downgrading the Windows SDK version worked for me. Tested with version 1803.

Comment: On what OS version?

Comment: @manuell Server2k19